# Julia CUDA - Saving intermediate kernel results without CPU

Tags: cuda, julia, gpu

Consider the following CUDA kernel, which computes the mean of each row of a 2-D matrix.

```
using CUDA

function mean!(x, n, out)
    """out = sum(x, dims=2)"""
    row_idx = (blockIdx().x-1) * blockDim().x + threadIdx().x
    for i = 1:n
        @inbounds out[row_idx] += x[row_idx, i]
    end
    out[row_idx] /= n
    return
end
```

```
using Test

nrow, ncol = 1024, 10
x = CuArray{Float64, 2}(rand(nrow, ncol))
y = CuArray{Float64, 1}(zeros(nrow))
@cuda threads=256 blocks=4 row_sum!(x, size(x)[2], y)
@test isapprox(y, sum(x, dims=2))  # test passed
```

Also consider the following CUDA kernel

```
function add!(a, b, c)
    """ c = a .+ b """
    i = (blockIdx().x-1) * blockDim().x + threadIdx().x
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i]
    return
end
```

```
a = CuArray{Float64, 1}(zeros(nrow))
b = CuArray{Float64, 1}(ones(nrow))
c = CuArray{Float64, 1}(zeros(nrow))
@cuda threads=256 blocks=4 add!(a, b, c)
@test all(c .== a .+ b)  # test passed
```

Now, suppose I wanted to write another kernel that uses the intermediate results of `mean!()`. For example,

```
function g(x, y)
    """ mean(x, dims=2) + mean(y, dims=2) """
    xrow, xcol = size(x)
    yrow, ycol = size(y)
    
    mean1 = CuArray{Float64, 1}(undef, xrow)
    @cuda threads=256 blocks=4 mean!(x, xcol, mean1)

    mean2 = CuArray{Float64, 1}(zeros(yrow))
    @cuda threads=256 blocks=4 mean!(y, ycol, mean2)

    out = CuArray{Float64, 1}(zeros(yrow))
    @cuda threads=256 blocks=4 add!(mean1, mean2, out)
    return out
end
```

(Of course, `g()` isn't technically a kernel since it returns something.)

My question is whether `g()` is "correct". In particular, is `g()` wasting time by transferring data between the GPU/CPU?

For example, if my understanding is correct, one way `g()` could be optimized is by initializing `mean2` the same way we initialize `mean1`. This is because when constructing `mean2`, we're actually first creating `zeros(yrow)` on the CPU, then passing this to the `CuArray` constructor to be copied to the GPU. In contrast, `mean1` is constructed but uninitialized (due to the `undef`) and therefore avoids this extra transfer.

To summarize, how do I save/use intermediate kernel results while avoiding data transfers between the CPU/GPU as much as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate arrays or vectors of zeros directly on GPU!

Try:

```
CUDA.zeros(Float64, nrow)
```

Some benchmarks:

```
julia> @btime CUDA.zeros(Float64, 1000,1000)
  12.600 μs (26 allocations: 1.22 KiB)
1000×1000 CuArray{Float64, 2, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}:
...

julia> @btime CuArray(zeros(1000,1000))
  3.551 ms (8 allocations: 7.63 MiB)
1000×1000 CuArray{Float64, 2, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}:
...
```